# RSA: How to compute plaintexts knowing ciphertexts, public key and relation between plaintexts

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

I'm trying to solve an exercise where you have to compute two plaintexts $p_1$ and $p_2$, knowing the corresponding ciphertexts $c_1$ and $c_2$ and the public key, of which $e=3$, and $n$ is a large number. 
Also given is a relation between $p_1$ and $p_2$. $p_2 = c_1 \cdot p_1 + c_2$. Where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

I'm guessing I should use the fact that $e$ is a low number (3) since RSA is unsafe in this case. I'm not sure where to start, how should I go about solving this exercise?

Comment: By the way, is this a homework exercise?

Comment: Do the two occurences of $c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively refer to the same number?

Comment: The lack of safety of textbook RSA encryption with public exponent $e=3$ is due more to the lack of proper encryption padding than it is due to the low exponent. Independently, I guess that $p_2 = k_1 \cdot p_1 + k_2$ where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are given constants unrelated to given ciphertexts $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an exercise, I'll provide the links of the articles as a **hint**;

The linearity of the messages  is first studied when $e=3$

- [Low-Exponent RSA with Related Messages](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_1.pdf) by Don Coppersmith, Matthew Franklin, Jacques Patarin, Michael Reitert, EUROCRYPT 1996: Advances in Cryptology — EUROCRYPT ’96 pp 1-9

A more general case, where $e$ is not limited to 3 and the relation is linear is studied in

- [A New Related Message Attack on RSA](https://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2005/33860001/33860001.pdf) Oded Yacobi and Yacov Yacobi, PKC 2005: Public Key Cryptography - PKC 2005 pp 1-8.

It is quite clear that these attacks are related to textbook RSA and it must not be used in practice.

For encryption, RSA has used either PKCS#1.5 padding or OAEP. Actually, we don't use RSA for encryption. We prefer it in digital signatures and that requires PSS padding or for Key Encapsulation, RSA-KEM.

Comment: As our current policy of the HW questions, I'll delete this answer when the question is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however the articles you provided are a bit overwhelming to me. It just confuses me more honestly. Could you give me a more concrete hint or example as to how to find the plaintext of a cipher text when e=3? Also, what's the point of the given relation between the two plaintexts?

Comment: Section 2 of the first paper, you want the formula just above the one labeled 1, and the first formula listed ($m2=\alpha m1+\beta$).

Comment: Thank you so much @SAIPeregrinus. You saved me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Also thanks @kelalaka (sorry for late reply), even though you could've just pointed me to the formula instead of having me waste time looking through papers I don't understand. :)

Comment: It is a homework, right?